# Switch value for clicked button from group of buttons in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to make a website using asp.net mvc 4 & jQuery 1.9.1 where I want to insert boolean values `(Y or N)` in textbox for the corresponding button pressed. It works for a single button, but it's not working for group of buttons. Here are my codes,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var isClicked = 0;
    $('.btn').click(function () {
        if (isClicked == 0) {
            isClicked = 1;
            $(this).toggleClass('color-blue color-green');
            $(this).next('.assignCheck').val('Y');
        } else if (isClicked == 1) {
            isClicked = 0;
            $(this).toggleClass('color-green color-blue');
            $(this).next('.assignCheck').val('N');
        }
    });
});
```

[**JSFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/s4y97kka/1/)

How can I make the buttons work individually?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

uYou can use data- attributes with button to store if its click value is 1 or zero and use that value to update the respective textbox

[Live Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/s4y97kka/2/)

*Html*

```
<button class="btn color-blue" data-clicked="0">ONE</button>
<input type="text" class="assignCheck" /><br><br>
<button class="btn color-blue" data-clicked="0">TWO</button>
<input type="text" class="assignCheck" /><br><br>
<button class="btn color-blue" data-clicked="0">THREE</button>
<input type="text" class="assignCheck" />
```

*JQuery*

```
$(document).ready(function () {        
    $('.btn').click(function () {
        var isClicked = $(this).data("clicked");        
        if (isClicked == 0) {
            isClicked = 1;
            $(this).toggleClass('color-blue color-green');
            $(this).next('.assignCheck').val('Y');
        } else if (isClicked == 1) {
            isClicked = 0;
            $(this).toggleClass('color-green color-blue');
            $(this).next('.assignCheck').val('N');
        }
        $(this).data("clicked", isClicked);
    });
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. But can you provide a code so that I can understand?

Comment: Awesome. Worked smoothly. Thanks. :)